# Simulating the "continue" directive, and other alternatives

Tags: loops, continue, povray

Some programming languages support a "continue" directive in loops to skip to the next loop. How do you achieve the same thing in languages that don't have this directive? I am facing a situation now in povray where I need this behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, just use a conditional:

```
#for (i, from, to)
  // do common actions
  #if (<condition is true>)
    // do something special to the condition
  #end
#end
```

Alternatively, POV-Ray 3.7 [supports the #break statement](http://www.povray.org/documentation/3.7.0/r3_3.html#r3_3_2_6_4) that you can use to emulate `continue` with a little help from recursion - however, this is quite clumsy and inelegant:

```
#macro LoopWithContinuation(from, to)
  #for (i, from, to)
    #if (<condition is true>)
      LoopWithContinuation(i + 1, to)
      #break
    #else
      // do something
    #end
    #debug ""
  #end
#end

LoopWithContinuation(1, 20)
```

Keep in mind, though, that POV-Ray has a fixed recursion depth limit of 200, so this approach is not suitable for longer loops.